# How to change width of dat.gui dropdown menu and deselect item

Tags: javascript, html, dat.gui

I'm using the [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) library in javascript and I have two questions:

1. How to change the width of a dat.gui dropdown menu?
2. How to de-select a dropdown menu item without selecting another?

Initializing the dropdown

```js
const indexParams = {
  index: -1,
};
const indexGUI = gui.addFolder("Index");
indexGUI.open();
const indexDropdown = indexGUI.add(indexParams, "index", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Image of the dropdown before interaction
[image: Initial Dropdown]

Comment: What do you mean by `de-select` is your select before you choose a value?

Comment: When the dropdown is first created, there is no value "selected". Once you click a value in the dropdown, that value is "selected". I'm trying to return to the state where there's no value "selected" in the dropdown

Comment: Could you show what your initial object looks like and how do you add the control?

Comment: I've added the code snippet and an image of the initial dropdown to my post

Comment: [width property](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md#GUI+width)

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe the control has a width property. I get an `undefined` when I try to access or change it. It looks like the width property is for the GUI itself. Changing that doesn't seem to affect the dropdown control width.